# How to recover my system from a failed upgrade due connection lost?

Tags: upgrade

So the other day I wanted to upgrade Ubuntu but my laptop lost internet connection half-way, and now Ubuntu is only half-upgraded and I can't access anything anymore... I can't reconnect to the internet as this function is not there anymore (due to the half-upgrade I guess), and when trying to click on anything or search for anything nothing happens... 
Do I have to set it up again fully now? And if so, how can I save all my data and stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't connect to the internet because the function is missing, you will most likely have to re-install Ubuntu. That said, backing up your data is easy as Ubuntu install discs have a live session you can use to access files on the computer.

Just boot up the install disc (I recommend the 13.10 release, so you don't have to upgrade again) and choose Try Ubuntu. Let it complete loading and you can now navigate through all your files. Just plug-in a USB drive with enough space on it, and copy all the stuff you need to the new drive. Safely remove the drive and start your installation.

PS: Next time, be sure to upgrade when power is connected, internet is stable and you have the time for it to complete.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Will try it asap! (And this time I do have a much better connection ^^)
Oh, and if you don't mind, one more question: Last time when I installed Ubuntu, I had the problem of only having 30gb of storage available, and I don't know why... What did I do wrong? I heard that there are two ways to install Ubuntu, and apparantly I did it the wrong way back then...?

Comment: Sounds like you may be dual booting. 30 GB is plenty for Ubuntu though, aslong as you don't install a ton of games. What partitions are on your drive?